# Wall sheathing sticking over the concrete base

Tags: sheathing

[image]

I found that my exterior wall has more than one wood panels inside, and they are held together by a piece of steel on the bottom. And the wood panels just stick out from the concrete base. Is this normal? Why did they do this? I thought the wall should be on the same level as the concrete base.

Comment: Looks like a good place for air, insects, and mice to get into the wall.

Comment: exactly. @UnhandledExcepSean any ideas why it was built like that?

Answer (score 0):

It was built like that so rain would run down and drip off outside of the foundation wall.

However, there should have been some type of seal to keep bugs and critters from making your home theirs. ( As others said.)

You could try spray foaming under there, but it will be messy.

Comment: Not sure I'd do spray foam there; it would act like a dam and force possible water that makes it through the exterior cladding into the home.